# How to improve speed when manually adding a border around non-alpha pixels in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've written [a script](https://github.com/Joncom/impact-font-sugar) which takes an image like this one (normally the black is alpha):

[image: font]

...and adds a border of any color you'd like:

[image: fonts with borders]

However it's not very fast. It takes about 130ms to create the border layer as a canvas for this tiny font. Bigger fonts take much longer!

The logic is simple:

```
/* This is more or less psuedo-code. */

// Blank image data where I will put the border.
var newData = newContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// The image I will be analyzing.
var oldData = oldContext.getImageData(0, 0, this.data.width, this.data.height);

// Loop through every pixel in oldData and remember where non-alpha pixels are.
var fontPixels = this._getNonAlphaPixels(oldData);

// Loop through relevant pixels, remember neighboring pixels, and add border.
for (var px in fontPixels) {
    for (var py in fontPixels[px]) {

        var borderPixels = this._getBorderPixels(px, py);
        for (var bx in borderPixels) {
            for (var by in borderPixels[bx]) {

                if (typeof fontPixels[bx] !== 'undefined' && 
                    typeof fontPixels[bx][by] !== 'undefined') 
                {
                    continue; // Do not draw borders inside of font.
                }

                newData.data[((newData.width * by) + bx) * 4] = color.red;
                newData.data[((newData.width * by) + bx) * 4 + 1] = color.green;
                newData.data[((newData.width * by) + bx) * 4 + 2] = color.blue;
                newData.data[((newData.width * by) + bx) * 4 + 3] = 255; //alpha
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm wondering: does someone know an alternative method which does not require pixel-by-pixel manipulation? Or perhaps is there a significant optimization that can be made to the above logic?

I should mention that `_getNonAlphaPixels`'s execusion time is negligible. And `_getBorderPixels`'s execution time is only is 17% of the total time.

**EDIT**

The below selected answer works wonderfully. The only significant difference between my solution and the one below is that whenever text is drawn, I draw an image instead (of a font).

Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in several way.

### Technique 1

One is to use the built-in `strokeText` function with draws the outline of a text. Setting `lineWidth` will determine the thickness of the border. However, the result is not always satisfying:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.font = font;
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeText(txt, x, y);
```

Results in:

[image: Demo 1]

<kbd>**[TEXT WITH BORDER DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/NS6BA/)**</kbd>

Text and canvas is currently not so accurate at a sub-pixel level which has to do with how the font-hinting is used (or rather is not used), anti-aliasing and other aspects.

### Technique 2

In any case, you can achieve a much better result by manually drawing the text in a "circle" to create the border:

```
var thick = 2;

ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.font = font;

ctx.fillText(txt, x - thick, y - thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y - thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x + thick, y - thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x + thick, y);
ctx.fillText(txt, x + thick, y + thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y + thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x - thick, y + thick);
ctx.fillText(txt, x - thick, y);

ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
```

The result is much better as seen here:

[image: demo 2]

<kbd>**[TEXT WITH BORDER DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/YfDD4/)**</kbd>

### Technique 3

The drawback with this last technique is that we are asking canvas to render the text 9 times - that is waste of time - in theory... (see results).

To improve this we can at least reduce the times we draw text to two by caching the border text once as an image and use that to draw the border, then draw the final text on top.

Here `octx` represents an off-screen canvas context (`c` the off-screen canvas it self) to which we draw the text we'll use for border. Then we replace the circular `fillText` with `drawImage`. Notice we set *baseline* to top to easier get control where the text will end up .

```
octx.textBaseline = ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.fillStyle = color;
octx.font = ctx.font = font;
octx.fillText(txt, 0, 0);

ctx.drawImage(c, x - thick, y - thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x, y - thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x + thick, y - thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x + thick, y);
ctx.drawImage(c, x + thick, y + thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x, y + thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x - thick, y + thick);
ctx.drawImage(c, x - thick, y);

ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
```

The image result will be the same as the previous:

[image: demo 3]

<kbd>**[TEXT WITH BORDER DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/aK8Ew/)**</kbd>

### Technique 4

Note that if you want even thicker borders you will probably want to consider actually to do a circular draw - literally - by using cos/sin etc. The reason is because at higher offsets the borders will start to come apart:

[image]

Instead of adding a bunch of draws you can instead use Cos/Sin calculation to draw the text in a literal circle:

```
function drawBorderText(txt, x, y, font, color) {

    var thick = 7, 
        segments = 4,  /// number of segments to divide the circle in
        angle = 0,     /// start angle
        part,          /// degrees per segment, see below

        i = 0, d2r = Math.PI / 180;

    /// determine how many parts are needed. I just
    /// started with some numbers in this demo.. adjust as needed
    if (thick > 1) segments = 6;
    if (thick > 2) segments = 8;
    if (thick > 4) segments = 12;

    part = 360 / segments;

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.font = font;

    /// draw the text in a circle
    for(;i < segments; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(txt, x + thick * Math.cos(angle * d2r),
                          y + thick * Math.sin(angle * d2r));
        angle += part;
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
}
```

Note that in this case you might have to draw two rounds as for small points they won't have a solid center (see for instance the dot over the i).

[image]

A bit crude in this demo, but for example's sake. You can fine-adjust by setting different thresholds for segments as well as add an "inner round" where text contains like here small details (`i`).

<kbd>**[TEXT WITH BORDER DEMO 4](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/cPrEY/)**</kbd>

### Results

Note that result will depend on various factors:

- Font geometry itself (incl. font hinting).
- Browser implementation of text rendering and its optimizations
- CPU
- Hardware acceleration

For example, on a Atom single core based computer without hardware acceleration I get 16ms for both demo 2 and 3 in Firefox (Aurora) (sometimes the double for the text version).

In Chrome (Canary) on the same computer the text based one uses 1-3 ms while the cached uses around 5 ms.

The sin/cos approach takes about 8-11 ms on a slow computer (achieved 5 ms a couple of times - JSFiddle is not the best place to test performance).

I don't have access to other hardware at the moment to test (and the margins are very small here and I'm not sure JavaScript will be able to pick it up, which I believe is the case with Firefox in particular) but at least you will have in any case a great increase compared to using manual pixel manipulation.

Comment: "...if you want even thicker borders you will probably want to consider actually to do a circular draw - literally - by using cos/sin etc." Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by this please? I'm not sure I understand what benefit you could gain by using sin/cos instead of the "9 draws".

Comment: @Joncom the "thick" is offsetting the drawing. At a certain value it will start to come apart - in those cases you can either add more draws or use sin/cos to fill gaps that will appear. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/xjza3/

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the coming-apart that you mean. Yes, it could be resolved by adding in extra draws. However I am still not sure how you could use sin/cos to fill in the gaps. Would you mind explaining please? I only ask because the extra-drawing method adds significant execution time when the thickness is >= 3. Thickness of 1 takes 2ms. Thickness of 6 takes 240ms.

Comment: @Joncom sounds there is some problem with how you measure. I get between 6-10 ms on a slow computer with the last fiddle. In case you don't use the console-timer, here is a fiddle where I added timing (see in console). This is a bit more accurate than using Time stamp if that's what you're using. Try in f.ex. Chrome as that is more accurate (higher resolution) than FF: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/xjza3/1/ If you still get a high number let me know.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the sin/cos. Your responses have been everything I wanted and more! Thank you for being so helpful. And moreover, I appreciate how well organized and formatted your response was, as well as the fiddles. You rock.